# wildfly maven pluging https certificate issue

Tags: maven, ssl, wildfly

I am working on a server that has a certificate that is not included in the default trust store. Then I have created my own jks and include in MAVEN_OPTS.

```
set MAVEN_OPTS=-Xmx512m -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=mytruststore.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=mypass
```

This way using the wildfly-maven-plugin I'm able to deploy the war file.

However, the problem is that then I'm not able to download anything from the maven repositories as there are not valid certificates. Including the following options doesn't work.

```
-Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure=true -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.allowall=true -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.ignore.validity.dates=true
```

Then... I need to know if there is an option to include the trust keystore only when deploying with wildfly-maven-plugin. This probably has to be in the pom file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to solve the issue using `properties-maven-plugin`. Using this plugin I'm setting system properties to the desired value when the deploy (package phase) is run. In this phase I don't need to download stuff from any repositories, it is just connecting to the https wildfly instance.

Below I post the example of what I have done:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>wildfly-deploy</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>set-system-properties</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <properties>
                <property>
                  <name>javax.net.ssl.trustStore</name>
                  <value>${wildfly.trust_store.file}</value>
                </property>
                <property>
                  <name>javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword</name>
                  <value>${wildfly.trust_store.password}</value>
                </property>
              </properties>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```